# Conditional Removal of Duplicates from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list that has names in Column A and it contains duplicates.

Column B has dates in them, but some cells are blank.

Is there a way to ask Excel to remove duplicate rows based on name AND blank cells in Column B?

Comment: Well, if you aren't averse of doing by hand, you could first sort the results and then delete the offending cells.

Comment: Check [Microsoft Excel help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-HP010073941.aspx#BMfilter_by_selection) for filtering.

Comment: My dataset contains over 4,000 rows, so it seems like Excellll answer would best help in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a helper column and a filter.

Steps:

1. Insert a helper column that gives the number of records with that value in column A.

   ```
   =COUNTIF($A$2:$A$15,A2)
   ```

   In this case, `A2:A15` is all the values in column A and `A2` is the specific value for the row. Fill this formula all the way down to the end of your table.
   [image]
2. Next, apply a filter to your table. Filter for helper column values greater than 1 and Field2 values (your dates) that are blank.
   [image]
3. Select the matching rows (as pictured above) and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. This will clear out these rows. Remove the filter and your table will show with blank rows where the deleted records were.  [image]
4. Select your table and press <kbd>F5</kbd>. Click `Special...` and then choose to go to `Blanks`. Click `OK`. This will select all the blank records in your table. Right click the selected range and choose `Delete...` and `Shift cells up`. This will consolidate your table.
   [image]
5. If you need to remove any other duplicates (not just the duplicates with blank Field2 values), you can use the Remove Duplicates tool to accomplish this.

Comment: Thank you so much; extremely helpful. I found a lot of rows where the same patient also had two dates on column B. Is there a way to remove the rows with the older date? I have a dataset with over 4,000 rows. To give some perspective, I work at a health clinic and am extracting data of all patient visits from last year and I need to report their most recent lab result date.

Comment: You could sort the table by Date (descending, i.e., most recent first), then run Remove Duplicates based only on the Name column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Data tab, **Remove Duplicates** feature, but base it on both columns. This would remove rows where both the name and the blank cell are duplicated. It would also remove duplicates if both the name and the date were the same, which I would assume is appropriate (or maybe the dates don't duplicate for any one person).

Comment: The dates won't always duplicate, so I will need to choose the most recent date. The Remove Duplicates feature does not always choose the row containing data, nor does it always keep the most current date.